# How to join tables where a column is not null

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to join data from two tables into one where the USSN IS NOT NULL;

It works perfectly without the "WHERE CONTACT2.USSN IS NOT NULL" added to it.  I've tried different permutations without luck.

```sql
SELECT B.CONTACT,
       B.LASTNAME,
       B.PHONE1,
       B.PHONE2,
       B.PHONE3,
       A.ACCOUNTNO,
       A.USCOREEFX,
       A.USCORETUC,
       A.USCOREXPN,
       A.USCORE1EFX,
       A.USCORE1TUC,
       A.USCORE1XPN
FROM CONTACT2 A
INNER JOIN CONTACT1 B
ON A.ACCOUNTNO = B.ACCOUNTNO
WHERE USSN IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you post some sample data input and what you expect to see as output.

Comment: _"It works perfectly without"_ Show what you put in. Define "perfectly". Show what it looks like. Same for whatever the non-perfect output is.

Comment: "It works perfectly without" means the query runs successfully without the WHERE statement. How is that not clear? Obviously, that is where the problem is. All I needed to do was add the reference "A." to USSN column and it returns what I'm looking for. Syntax problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
SELECT B.CONTACT,
       B.LASTNAME,
       B.PHONE1,
       B.PHONE2,
       B.PHONE3,
       A.ACCOUNTNO,
       A.USCOREEFX,
       A.USCORETUC,
       A.USCOREXPN,
       A.USCORE1EFX,
       A.USCORE1TUC,
       A.USCORE1XPN
FROM CONTACT2 A
INNER JOIN CONTACT1 B
ON A.ACCOUNTNO = B.ACCOUNTNO
WHERE A.USSN IS NOT NULL
```